Understanding disassembly of compiled x86_64 code
I am trying to understand how stack frames work in a x86_64 system and the code discussed below is specifically for linux kernel (6.5.12) module that is using frame pointers (CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y and CONFIG_UNWINDER_FRAME_POINTER=yon top of x86_64_defconfig). The original intention was to learn manual stack unwinding.
I have the following dummy function in the dummy kernel module:
static void dummy_function_1(int arg1, char arg2) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "dummy_function_1: arg1=%d, arg2=%c\n", arg1, arg2);
    dummy_function_2("Hello", (struct dummy_struct){.a = arg1, .b = arg2});
}

When I disassemble this, I get the following :
0000000000000130 <dummy_function_1.constprop.0>:
 130:   55                      push   %rbp
 131:   ba 78 00 00 00          mov    $0x78,%edx
 136:   be 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%esi
 13b:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
 142:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 145:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   14a <dummy_function_1.constprop.0+0x1a>
 14a:   48 bf 2a 00 00 00 78    movabs $0x780000002a,%rdi
 151:   00 00 00
 154:   e8 77 ff ff ff          call   d0 <dummy_function_2.constprop.0>

I have the following queries :

Why there is no printk call in the assembly? Because in practice, when I load the module, the printk output is coming [   36.823046] dummy_function_1: arg1=42, arg2=x
Why we have mov    $0x0,%rdi ?
Why we didn't put 3 arguments to dummy_function_2 in 3 different registers %rdi, %rsi and %rdx? Why we have just movabs $0x780000002a,%rdi before calling dummy_function_2?

PS : Using gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
EDIT
I re-compile the module code with -Og flag and disassembled with objdump -d -r dummy_module.ko as per the suggestions. Below is what I get now :
0000000000000120 <dummy_function_1>:
 120:   55                      push   %rbp
 121:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 124:   41 54                   push   %r12
 126:   53                      push   %rbx
 127:   89 fb                   mov    %edi,%ebx
 129:   41 89 f4                mov    %esi,%r12d
 12c:   40 0f b6 d6             movzbl %sil,%edx
 130:   89 fe                   mov    %edi,%esi
 132:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
            135: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.8+0x118
 139:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   13e <dummy_function_1+0x1e>
            13a: R_X86_64_PLT32 _printk-0x4
 13e:   45 0f b6 e4             movzbl %r12b,%r12d
 142:   49 c1 e4 20             shl    $0x20,%r12
 146:   89 de                   mov    %ebx,%esi
 148:   4c 09 e6                or     %r12,%rsi
 14b:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
            14e: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.1+0x24
 152:   e8 79 ff ff ff          call   d0 <dummy_function_2>

Ques : "As for the printk call, the linker has yet to fill in the actual address". Since I was running objdump on the final .ko, this mean linker should have already ran. So ideally printk symbol offset should have already been inserted. Please correct me. Maybe I need to understand this linking/loading part again.

Do an unoptimized build, and look at the assembly code for that.

Note that your code has been optimised by means of constant propagation (see the .constprop.0 suffix in the symbol names).  This is likely why some parameters and arguments have been eliminated.  As for the printk call, it's likely the call at address 0x145; the linker has yet to fill in the actual address.  Try to add -r to objdump's options to see what address the call actually goes to.

Since it's not known at build-time where a module would be loaded, there has to be some kind of load-time rellocation as well. That what's the R prefix in R_X86_64_PLT32 means. As for the strings, they're in the .rodata.str1.* segments. And much of the rest is just moving data into the right places for the calls.

Thanks. One last confusion on the string. There are 132:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi and 135: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.8+0x118. I am assuming 48 c7 c7 correspond to mov    $0x0,%rdi and from offset 135 onwards i.e.  00 00 00 00 correspond to R_X86_64_32S?

@Naveen The R_X86_64_32S bit is a relocation, this is what -r outputs.  It means: at this address, the loader will patch in the address of that symbol as the given type of relocation (here, a 32 bit signed integer).  The instruction is the full seven bytes, but the relocation only modifies the last four of them, which is the integer to be loaaded.

"I have the following queries .." - Single question per question post, please.  Your additional "Ques" doesn't make the question post to be focused either.

printk() is a macro IIRC, _printk() is the real implementation in C for that call.
